# C# WPF DataGrid Style from ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles, row

If you want to fill a DataGrid, you can add them to give `Datagrid.ItemSource` a list of object. For example Person (name, age,...) or something else.

Is there a way to place some more (extra) information in Object (Person) to style each row in DataGrid individually, by only use `Datagrid.ItemSource = List<Person>` ?

Comment: Are you asking if you can style a datagrid row based on properties of the objects in the grids itemsource?

Comment: Yes, this is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you modify your Person class to contain that information. For instance you can put an icon in there and then have the DataGrid display a different icon per row. But this is a bit dirty.

Instead I would recommend using a Converter. When your data such as age is passed into the WPF window your converter will execute and you can return whatever you like, such as an icon, color etc... This way you can customize each row and keep the logic all in your converter without the Person class getting mixed up with UI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a DataGridTemplateColumn to the DataGrid's Columns collection and put any UIElement you want in its CellTemplate, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Gray" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```